# why can't match the content between # and end of line in sed?

Tags: sed

```
$ echo "haha#nihao" | sed "s/#.+$/end/"
haha#nihao
```

I want to match contents between character `#` and the end of line.why can't i get it?

```
:%!sed  "s/#.\+$/end/" 
E194:No alternate file name to substitute for '#'
```

problem 1:
why i can't use it in sed of vim?

problem 2:
how to see the EORROR 194 ?

Comment: An alternative to `.+` is `..*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> problem 1: why i can't use it in sed of vim?

Because by default `sed` uses [BRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions), basic regular expressions:

- `/.+/` this matches any character followed by a "+"
- `/.\+/` this matches one or more occurrences of any character

You can tell `sed` to use extended regular expressions with the `-r` flag in GNU implementations and `-E` flag with BSD implementations:

```
$ echo "haha#nihao" | sed -r "s/#.+$/end/"
hahaend
```

> problem 2: how to see the EORROR 194 ?

You get this error because `#` has a special meaning in `vim` when you run commands with `!`: `#` marks on the command line are replaced with the *alternate file*. It should work if you escape the `#`:

```
%!sed "s/\#.\+$/end/"
```

You can read about this error with the `:help E194` command, and about alternative file with `:help alternate-file`.

Answer (score 0):

use `sed -r`

```
echo "haha#nihao" | sed -r "s/#.+$/end/"
hahaend
```

from `man sed`

```
   -r, --regexp-extended

          use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

Comment: Too bad it's not portable. Works with GNU sed but not BSD sed.